# How can I use bluetooth on my phone to run a program on the EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, bluetooth

I tried the Commander app but it seems to just let you control individual motors.

I would like to run the various programs I have made using an input on the phone through Bluetooth

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Hi Emily, which phone are you using?

Answer (score 2):

There is an Android app called [EV3 mailbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.EV3.Mailbox) that can send messages to the EV3 brick. You can trigger your program to run in different ways by sending out different mailbox messages.